# How can i use ipyleaflet instead of folium in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, folium, ipyleaflet

I am working on a project for uni where im trying to get GPS data from a microcontroller and show the position using the pyqt5 web widget. First i used folium but i had to rerender the map everytime to move the marker which is a roundabout way of doing it. So i found ipyleaflet which can move and/or delete markers on will. BUT. Folium has a method `_repr_html_()` for converting the map to html and displaying it easy, but ipyleaflet doesnt have it. So i found a solution here on stackoverflow and adapted it to my code but it doesnt work for some reason.

Here is my code

```py
import sys
import json
from ipyleaflet import Map, Marker, LayersControl, basemaps
from ui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication

from ipywidgets import HTML, IntSlider
from ipywidgets.embed import embed_minimal_html, embed_data

class MyForm(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        html_template = """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>IPyWidget export</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.4/require.min.js" integrity="sha256-Ae2Vz/4ePdIu6ZyI/5ZGsYnb+m0JlOmKPjt6XZ9JJkA=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@jupyter-widgets/html-manager@^1.0.1/dist/embed-amd.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

            <script type="application/vnd.jupyter.widget-state+json">
              {manager_state}
            </script>
            
            <div id="ipyleaflet-map">
                <script type="application/vnd.jupyter.widget-view+json">
                    {widget_views}
                </script>
            </div>

          </body>
        </html>
        """
    
        self.m = Map(center=(24.179509715480204, 12.66299706912081), zoom=16)
        marker = Marker(location=(24.179509715480204, 12.66299706912081), tooltip="woohhooo")
        self.m.add_layer(marker)
        data = embed_data(views=[self.m])
        manager_state = json.dumps(data['manager_state'])
        # print(manager_state)
        widget_views = [json.dumps(data['view_specs'])]
        rendered_template = html_template.format(manager_state=manager_state, widget_views=widget_views)
        # print(rendered_template)
        self.ui.widget.setHtml(rendered_template)
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyForm()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And here is the code for the ui, its pretty simple

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'untitled.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.0
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(638, 400)
        self.widget = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(Dialog)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(9, 9, 621, 390))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog"))
```

And this is the error message that i get

```
js: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL
```

When i open the generated html file in a browser it works fine but my code errors for some reason.

EDIT: [How to add an Ipyleaflet map to a PyQt5 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65699474/how-to-add-an-ipyleaflet-map-to-a-pyqt5-application/65758917#65758917)
Here is the answer that i mentioned